# Should I use a different class/method/pattern to handle local-cloud syncing of data?

Tags: azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to Azure Mobile Services as well as mobile development.

From my experience in web development, retrieving data from the database is done part by part as the user requests more data i.e. the website doesn't load all the data on one go.

I'm implementing this principle in mobile app wherein data is loaded (if already in the local db) or downloaded (if not yet in the local db) as the user scrolls down.

I'm using Azure Mobile Services Sync Table to handle the loading of data in the app. However, i wont be able to paginate the downloading of data. According to this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f261ef1d-1f2e-41e5-870e-f724e4a3853c/how-can-i-implement-paging-if-incremental-pull-query-must-not-have-orderby-clause?forum=azuremobile), the PullAsync method downloads all data that has changed/added since its last sync and doesn't allow for using take/skip methods. This is because PullAsync uses incremental sync.

This would mean there will be a large download of data during the first ever launch of the app or if the app hasn't been online for a while even if the user hasn't requested for the said data (i.e. scrolled to it).

Is this a good way for handling data in mobile apps? I like using SyncTable cos it handles quite a lot of important data upload/download stuff e.g. data upload queuing, download/upload of data changes. I'm just concerned with downloading data that the user doesn't need yet.

Or maybe there's something i can do to limit the items PullAsync downloads? (aside from deleted = false and UserId = current user's UserId)

Currently, i limited the times PullAsync is called to the Loading Screen after the user logs in and when the user pulls to refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile development is very different from web development. While loading lots of data to a stateless web page is a bad thing, loading the same data to a mobile app might actually be a good thing. It can help app performance and usability.

The main purpose of using something like the offline data storage is for occasionally disconnected scenarios. There are always architectural tradeoffs that have to be considered. "How much is too much" is one of those tradeoffs. How many roundtrips to the server is too much? How much data transfer is too much? Can you find the right balance of the data that you pass to the mobile device? Mobile applications that are "chatty" with the servers can become unusable when the carrier signal is lost.

In your question, you suggest "maybe there's something i can do to limit the items PullAsync downloads". In order to avoid the large download, it may make sense for you to design your application to allow the user to set criteria for download. If UserId doesn't make sense, maybe a Service Date or a number of days forward or back in the schedule. Finding the right "partition" of data to load to the device will be a key consideration for usability of your app...both online and offline.

There is no one right answer for your solution. However, key considerations should be bandwidth, data plan limits, carrier coverage and user experience both connected and disconnected. Remember...your mobile app is "stateful" and you aren't limited to round-trips to the server for data. This means you have a bit of latitude to do things you wouldn't on a web page.

Comment: One additional comment here, specifically related to Azure Mobile Services.  You can create a VIEW of the data - either by adjusting the query server-side or by using an actual SQL VIEW.  The view of the data is the projection of the data set that the mobile device actually gets.  Many people, for example, use query adjustment to limit the data set that is presented (example: only receive "my" records based on authentication).

Comment: thanks Brian Sherwin. can you recommend any articles/books/sites where i can get a sense of mobile design principles and stuff? i'd insert the request in the question but was not sure if it would fit the stack overflow format for questions.

Comment: I don't have any specific books/sites that address exactly what you are looking for, but if you look at the following link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658108.aspx) you can get a sense of how to think about your application and general considerations.